# How to Remove a Div using variable parameters?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a way to add entries to my form so that the user can choose how many he wants, but I can't get the remove part working.

JavaScript

```
    var i = 1;
    var divContent = document.getElementById('formulario');

    //Click to add a field
    function cria() {
        //This add a HTML Inputs and divs who the ID is variable how the 'i' is increasedf
        document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML += '<div class="mb-1 col-3" id="div'+i+'"><label for="nomeTx0" class="form-label">Nome</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeTx'+i+'" name="nomeTx'+i+'" required></div><div class="mb-1 col-3" id="div2'+i+'"><label for="taxa'+i+'" class="form-label">Valor</label><input type="float" class="form-control" id="taxa'+i+'" name="taxa'+i+'" required></div><a href="#" data-id="1" onclick="remove(div'+i+',div2'+i+')" id="div'+i+'" id="adicionarCampo">- Remover campo</a>';
        i++;
    }
    function remove(div1, div2){
        var div = document.getElementById(div1);
        var div2 = document.getElementById(div2);
        div.remove();
        div2.remove();
        i--;
    }
```

And now the HTML

```
           <form>
                <h4 class="card-tittle text-center">Taxas</h4>
                <div id="formulario" class="form row align-items-start">
                    <div class="mb-1 col-3" id="0">
                      <label for="nomeTx0" class="form-label">Nome</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeTx0" name="nomeTx0" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-1 col-3" id="0">
                      <label for="taxa0" class="form-label">Valor</label>
                      <input type="float" class="form-control" id="taxa0" name="taxa0" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <a href="#" data-id="1" onclick="cria()" id="adicionarCampo">+ adicionar campo</a>
                <div class="mb-1 col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary col-5" id="Enviar" type="submit" text="Enviar">Adicionar Taxas</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

ID="taxa"+i but when I call the remove(); error is printed to me saing the variable is null.

Answer (score 1):

### **This is really not the right approach in the first place.**

Your fundamental problem is that you are relying on `id`s to know what element(s) to add and remove and this is leading you to concatenate an `id` onto dynamically created elements, made from long strings with variables concatenated into them. **In reality, you should avoid `id`s whenever possible as they make your code very brittle and don't scale well.**

This is a perfect use for the HTML [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element. As you can see from the re-worked code below, all `id`s have been removed - - you don't need them. Additionally, instead of long strings with a variable concatenated into it, you just need to copy/clone the template whenever you need one. Then, you can use ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and smartly organized HTML to just set up a single `click` event on a master wrapper element, where the actual element that was clicked (the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)) can be checked. If it was a remove button, then just remove the entire wrapper [that is the nearest ancestor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to the remove button that was clicked.

You can now add and remove as many items as you like with no need for an `id` or counting variables!

```js
// Get a reference to the template, outer div and the add "button"
const template = document.querySelector("template");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const add = document.querySelector(".add");

// Set up the add event in Javascript, not with inline HTML
add.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true); // Clone the template
  wrapper.appendChild(clone);
});

// Set up a wrapper level click event that any clicks within it will bubble up to
wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Test to see if it was remove "button" that was clicked
  if(event.target.classList.contains("remove")){
    // Just remove the closest ancestor div that holds that particular group
    // and remove it.
    event.target.closest("div.templateWrapper").remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.mb-1.col-lg-12 {
  text-align:center;
}

.mb-1.col-3 {
  margin:2px;
}

.add, .remove {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:blue;
}

.labelName { display:inline-block; width:3em; }

/* This is just to better see the groups */
.templateWrapper, .form {
  background-color:aliceblue;
  padding:5px;
  margin:8px;
}
```

```html
<!-- This will not initially be shown on the page.
     It will be used to copy from when/if needed. -->
<template>
  <div class="templateWrapper">
    <div class="mb-1 col-3">
      <label class="form-label"><span class="labelName">Nome</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeTx" required>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-1 col-3">
      <label class="form-label"><span class="labelName">Valor</span>
        <!-- An input does not have a type=float -->
        <input class="form-control" name="taxa" required>
      </label>
    </div>
    <span class="remove">- Remover campo</span>
  </div>
</template>

<form>
  <h4 class="card-tittle text-center">Taxas</h4>
  <!-- Hyperlinks are for navigation, not JavaScript click hooks. Any visible element
       supports a click event. Use span and div for generic clickable inline or block 
       elements that need to have click event handlers. -->
  <span class="add">+ adicionar campo</span>  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="form row align-items-start">
      <div class="mb-1 col-3">
        <label class="form-label"><span class="labelName">Nome</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeTx0" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-1 col-3">
        <label class="form-label"><span class="labelName">Valor</span>
          <input type="float" class="form-control" name="taxa0" required>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-1 col-lg-12">
    <!-- A button does not have a "text" attribute -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary col-5" type="submit">Adicionar Taxas</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The only thing I don't entirely agree with is your "Hyperlink is for navigation" comment. An anchor is not necessarily a hyperlink. And the developer's intention here is clear: they want the style of a hyperlink for something that doesn't go anywhere, but runs some code instead. I for one don't understand why styling a generic element to look like a hyperlink is considered "ok" while using the browser's native "hyperlink" styling is considered "not ok"? Especially since they both achieve the same result, but the second one with less effort.

Comment: @tao [Anchors are for navigation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) If they don't cause resource to be navigated to, then they serve to set a point as a destination. That's the semantic purpose of them. Users who rely on assistive technologies can experience problems when anchors are used for other purposes than navigation. Using them for any other reason is semantically incorrect and doesn't comply with accessibility standards.

Comment: @tao Also (as I assume you know), style is separate from the native HTML rendering. This is evidenced by the widespread misuse of HTML heading elements because most users just use the one that presents the text in the font size they like and not because of a document structure they are trying to create. In short, never use an HTML element because of the native styling it produces, use the right HTML element for the semantic purpose it was intended for.

Comment: I know the argument. The problem I have with is that, practically, it translates into: tricking people who can't see into believing that's a hyperlink is not ok. But tricking people who can see (> 99.99% of internet users) is perfectly fine. I've coded for people who need assistive technologies. Probably more than the average senior. And the tools used are a lot smarter than the general conception about them. I can assure you they had no trouble whatsoever with `javascript:void(0)` generations ago. No confusion there.

Comment: @tao I don't see the logic in those statements. Neither is a trick. In one case, you're using semantically incorrect code that will cause accessibility issues and in another you're not. Styling is a completely separate matter. What I will say is that, from a UX point of view, it probably shouldn't be presented to look like a link in the first place, but rather a button or image instead. I only used a link look here because that's what the OP had.

Comment: @tao Have you had experience with screen readers or [WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/aria/) or [Section 508](https://www.section508.gov/)? We're not talking about seniors who need reading glasses.

Comment: @tao And, sorry for the rant, but `javascript:void(0)` is a holdover to the days before standards. While it still works today, it's not considered a best practice as are many techniques still widely used today because people just copy other people's code without knowing any better.

Comment: I wasn't talking about this case. I was talking about the general case, because you made a generalization: hyperlinks are for navigation. I was talking about the following case: a navigation menu. The client wants you to put an extra menu entry which displays a banner, a modal or changes some setting. Do you actually tell them: *"That's semantically incorrect. We have to use an element that is not styled like a link and is not a link, because we're not navigating anywhere"*? The requirement is that it looks like all the rest. Do you tell them: *"go find someone else to code your website"*?

Comment: @tao Yes, exactly. And, I'd follow that up with, "If we don't, we won't be compliant with accessibility standards and so some visitors may not experience the site as intended."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230738/discussion-between-tao-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score 0):

You would like to pass the ids of the html elements to function remove , instead you pass something else.

Try this:

```
function remove(d1, d2){
        //what are passing to function...  id , or something else ?
        console.log(d1,d2);  
    
        // now I force the arguments passed to function to a valid value id for test

 
        var a = document.getElementById('div1'); // id is div1 
        var b = document.getElementById('div21'); // id is div21

        //Ask to parentNode to remove his child  
 
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);   
        b.parentNode.removeChild(b);                   
        i--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you don't pass a **string** to the **remove** function but instead you pass the whole element. That is why **document.getElementById** can't find anything because it expects a **string** as a parameter. I refactored you code a bit and also when removing the fields the link **- Remover campo** stayed and was not deleted. I fixed that as well by passing a third argument to the remove function.

```
    var i = 1;
var divContent = document.getElementById('formulario');

//Click to add a field
function cria() {
    //This add a HTML Inputs and divs who the ID is variable how the 'i' is increasedf
    document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML += '<div class="mb-1 col-3" id="div'+i+'"><label for="nomeTx0" class="form-label">Nome</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeTx'+i+'" name="nomeTx'+i+'" required></div><div class="mb-1 col-3" id="div2'+i+'"><label for="taxa'+i+'" class="form-label">Valor</label><input type="float" class="form-control" id="taxa'+i+'" name="taxa'+i+'" required></div><a href="#" data-id="1" onclick="remove(`div'+i+'`, `div2'+i+'`, `div'+i+'remove`)" id="div'+i+'remove" id="adicionarCampo">- Remover campo</a>';
    i++;
}
function remove(div1, div2, link){
    var div = document.getElementById(div1);
    var div2 = document.getElementById(div2);
    var link = document.getElementById(link);
    divContent.removeChild(div);
    divContent.removeChild(div2);
    divContent.removeChild(link)
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do your code working it change your function "cria". (it's not the best option)

You miss ' '.
You have this.

```
onclick="remove(div'+i+',div2'+i+')"
```

You need this.

```
onclick="remove(\'div'+i+'\',\'div2'+i+'\')"
```

Javascript just doesn't understand that these parameters are strings.

And the full function "cria" after changes.

```
function cria() {
    //This add a HTML Inputs and divs who the ID is variable how the 'i' is increasedf
    document.getElementById('formulario').innerHTML += '<div class="mb-1 col-3" id="div'+i+'"><label for="nomeTx0" class="form-label">Nome</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeTx'+i+'" name="nomeTx'+i+'" required></div><div class="mb-1 col-3" id="div2'+i+'"><label for="taxa'+i+'" class="form-label">Valor</label><input type="float" class="form-control" id="taxa'+i+'" name="taxa'+i+'" required></div><a href="#" data-id="1" onclick="remove(\'div'+i+'\',\'div2'+i+'\')" id="div'+i+'" id="adicionarCampo">- Remover campo</a>';
    i++;
}
```